# Does the specific ABI of a particular ERC20 token have to be used in order to interract with it?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, abi

....Or can the standard, static ERC20 ABI be used for any ERC20 token equally?

Namely, in a custom ERC20 token (smart contract) there can exist any function(s) the author of a token may have implemented. And in order to interract with those functions, one is required to use the special ABI that describes them, right?

At the same time, a few times I've read that the standard  ABI of ERC20 is **enough** to interract with **ANY** ERC20 token even if a token may follow the ERC20 standard **precisely.**

How can this enough? How would one call a function `myCustomFunc(....)` a ERC20 token  may contain and using **only the standard ERC20 ABI**? Because following the ERC20 standard doesn't mean that a token may not contain any additional, non-standard, custom functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever said the standard ABI for ERC20 is enough to interact with any ERC20 must have meant **generally**. And you are right to say that if you use a standard ERC20 ABI you won't be able to call `myCustomFunction()`. I mean technically you can, and you don't even need an ABI to interact with a contract if you know its functions signatures (the 4 bytes signature).

In an ABI you have the definitions of some functions you can use along with the types of parameters they expect. In a Standard ERC20 ABI, I'd expect to find `transfer`, `approve`, `balanceOf` and such.

If you know what parameters `myCustomFunction` takes, it's pretty trivial to add it. Look for any function definition inside your ABI (it's just JSON, it doesn't bite) and copy the format

### Wait, what's a 4-byte signature?

Transactions on the Ethereum blockchain are all the same thing: they have a caller (`address`), a callee (`address`), some data (`bytes`) and some value (`uint256`). In that sense, look at all transactions wether it is calling a function on a smart contract, sending ETH to a friend, sending a string message, or sending nothing as relatively the same thing.

What diferenciates contract functions call is that when you call a smart contract, it can read the data you send and it can do stuff with it like computing, storing, calling other addresses with value and data or reverting the transaction.

For any transaction that calls a function on a smart contract, by convention, the first 4 bytes of the call data contain what's called a selector or a function signature. The 4 bytes are obtained by hashing the function signature and truncating. for example for the function:

```
function transfer(address to, amount uint256) external {
  // ...
}
```

You would hash the string `transfer(address,amount)` with keccak256 and you would get `a9059cbb2ab09eb219583f4a59a5d0623ade346d962bcd4e46b11da047c9049b`

The first 4 bytes are

- a9
- 05
- 9c
- bb

therefore the selector `0xa9059cbb` corresponds to the `transfer` function. If you look at any call of `transfer(address,uint256)` in Etherscan and look at the raw calldata you'll see it starts with that selector.

if you use a library like `ethers` in JS to interact with contracts, what it does with the ABI is compute the selector from the function name and argument types and it builds the calldata from that.

Comment: `I mean technically you can, and you don't even need an ABI to interact with a contract if you know its functions signatures (the 4 bytes signature).` --> what do you mean? How? What's "4 bytes signature"?

Comment: I was hoping you'd ask I'll edit my answer ;)